# MS Botframework - Access to intent and message

Tags: analytics, botframework

Is it possible to create a plugin that has access to both intent and message at the same time in botframework?  I'm specifically interested in creating a plugin that can send the message that was received as well as the intent that was registered and used to outside analytics.

Comment: Are you using .NET or Node SDK for BotBuilder?

Comment: I'd be interested in the capability for both, I assume .NET would be harder to do it in though?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [intercept and log messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-middleware#intercept-and-log-messages) via custom middleware.

The following code sample shows how to intercept messages that are exchanged between user and bot using the concept of middleware in the Bot Builder SDK for .NET.

First, create a DebugActivityLogger class and define a LogAsync method to specify what action is taken for each intercepted message. This example just prints some information about each message.

```
public class DebugActivityLogger : IActivityLogger
{
    public async Task LogAsync(IActivity activity)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"From:{activity.From.Id} - To:{activity.Recipient.Id} - Message:{activity.AsMessageActivity()?.Text}");
    }
}
```

Then, add the following code to Global.asax.cs. Every message that is exchanged between user and bot (in either direction) will now trigger the LogAsync method in the DebugActivityLogger class.

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<DebugActivityLogger>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerDependency();
        builder.Update(Conversation.Container);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
}
```

For a complete middleware code example, see: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-Middleware

Comment: Thanks, would I be misreading this as the message only though?

Comment: Would that be "activity.AsMessageActivity()?.Type" or something else?

Comment: This is for intercepting Bot Framework messages.  By "intents" do you mean LUIS intents?

Comment: Yeah LUIS intent's